# Azure Managed Instance :: Why Extended Stored Procedure are listed?

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm creating a security assessment for an Azure Managed Instance.

The Vulnerability Assessment that I find on the Azure portal alerts me that there are 6 Extended Stored Procedure that could harm my Managed Instance:

[image]

Strange... I taught that Extended Stored Procedure weren't supported on Azure Managed Instance.

And in fact:

- [This documentation proves it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server#stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers)
- [This documentation proves it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison#features-of-sql-database-and-sql-managed-instance)

So why the official Azure Vulnerability Assessment is marking this with medium risk?

Is this a false positive?

Comment: Was this an older database migrated into Azure at some point?

Comment: Oh, yeah @TimothyG. this is a freshly SQL Server 2012 migrated to Managed Instance. I'm all ears, tell me where is the problem.

Comment: I wonder since this was an older SQL Server instance that was migrated, perhaps your DB or `master` contains these stored procedures still.  If you go to `Your DB` → Programmability → Stored Procedures → System Stored Procedures in SSMS for the instance, do you see the procedures in question (or do you see them under just "Stored Procedures")? If they are there, then I would say they were carried over during the migration, in which case, you can probably safely delete them, since they need specific DLL files to be present to even work, and since Azure doesn't support them, they won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Extended SPs are supported in SQL MI.

The documentation should be updated.

It is easy to put this to the test, example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same viewpoint with @Timothy G. These stored procedures are not supported in Azure SQL database. If they are exist in your source SQL Server, it may be transferred in to Azure SQL database. But they won't work.

I don't  know how you migrate your SQL Server to Azure SQL database. You can use [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to asses you SQL server first:

- Assess on-premises SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package(s)
  migrating to Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance. The
  assessment helps to discover issues that can affect the migration.
  These are described as compatibility issues and are organized in the
  following categories:

  Migration blockers: discovers the compatibility issues that block
  migrating source package(s) to Azure. DMA provides recommendations to
  help you address those issues.

  Information issues: detects partially supported or deprecated
  features that are used in source package(s).

May be you can find the reason.

Comment: Thank you confirming, I opened an issue about this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/75890. Now sure how they migrated this database to the MI but the Vulnerability Assessement is wrong.

Comment: @LeonYue Is there a way to remove these `extended stored procedures` from the `Azure SQL Managed Instance`?